# Using SharedPreferences to store and retrieve int

Tags: java, android, variables, sharedpreferences

This is driving me crazy. Cannot seem to get this to work at all. I'm pretty inexperienced so any tips would be grand. I hope it is just a stupid mistake that someone can explain.

A number is derived in one class. The number is then used within that class without a problem. Within that Class I store that number using the shared preferences method. However in a later Class when I attempt to retrieve that number the app crashes out.

This is the class where I process and try to store the number:

```
public class Summary extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.summary);

        int Time = gotTime();

        // Create object of SharedPreferences.
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Summary.this);
        //now get Editor
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        //put your value
        editor.putInt("TargetTime", Time);
        //commits your edits
        editor.

// I then display the Time on that screen which all works ok
        TextView textViewT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textViewT.setText("Time is " + Time); 

};


    public int gotTime(){

//do stuff to generate the value for time stored as variable PenileTim   

    return PenileTim;

};
}
```

Then in a future class I try to retrieve the Time:

```
public class Map extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);


        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        int VarTime = sharedPref.getInt("TargetTime", (Integer) null);

            TextView textViewP = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTest);
        textViewP.setText(" " + VarTime );

        }
 }
```

Anybody have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Be specific about the crash. Supply your logcat.

Comment: In your first class, should editor. be editor.commit(); ?

Comment: You have to be careful when using `getDefaultSharedPreferences()`. Use  the application context like this: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`.

Comment: Do not use putInt()/getInt(). Instead convert to String and use putString()/getString(). I never got the first pair to work also.

Comment: I converted it to a string and it worked fine.

Comment: Annoying that the GetInt didn't work though.

Thanks for your help!